# grpc, two clients connect to the server at one time return error

Tags: node.js, grpc

i wrote a simple chat room demo with grpc lib, but only one client can connect to the server at one time, weird. Here is my code, can anyone give my some advise on it?

[full code Link from Github](https://github.com/ChopperLee2011/grpc-examples/tree/master/examples/chatRoom)

client:

```
const chat_proto = grpc.load(__dirname + '/chat.proto').demo;
const client = new chat_proto.Chat('localhost:50051');
```

server:

```
let chatServer = getService();
chatServer.bind('localhost:50051');
chatServer.listen();
```

chat.proto:

```
syntax = "proto3";
package demo;
service Chat {
  rpc sayHi(userName) returns (welMessage) {}

  rpc ChatWith(stream chatNote) returns (stream chatNote) {}

}
message userName {
  string name = 1;
}
message welMessage {
  string message = 1;
}

message chatNote {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Error:

- client return `Error at /Users/chopper/WebstormProjects/grpcexamples/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:461:23` which means response.status.code !== grpc.status.OK
- server return `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: Can you also include 'chat.proto', so that your example is fully reproducible?

Comment: Actually, the service implementation code would also be useful.

Comment: thanks for reading, i add proto file, and if you want see detail, i add my github code link.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to connect?

Comment: I tried to run the code in that repository, and both Node.js and io.js tell me that the first line is a syntax error. And I can't find any mention of this `node-es6`. What interpreter did you use to run your code?

Comment: node-es6 is a npm lib, you can install it by `npm install node-es6 -g`, [npm link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-es6);iojs seem not support `import` for now, [issue link](https://github.com/nodejs/io.js/issues/1000)

Comment: OK, I got the examples running, but I can't reproduce your problem. What versions of Node.js and grpc are you using?